# MySQL: Strange behavior of query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following three queries:

This query returns 427

```
select count(distinct patient_id) from patient_visits where lower(gender) = 'male';
```

This query returns 272

```
select count(distinct patient_id) from patient_visits where lower(gender) = 'female';
```

Both the following query returns 687

```
select count(distinct patient_id) from patient_visits where lower(gender) in ('male', 'female');
select count(distinct patient_id) from patient_visits where lower(gender) = 'male' or lower(gender) = 'female';
```

Why the result from last queries is not 427 + 272 = 699?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some patients have both "male" and "female" assigned as a gender.  You can find them:

```
select patient_id
from patient_visits
where lower(gender) in ('male', 'female')
group by patient_id
having count(distinct lower(gender)) = 2;
```

Note that in a medical setting you may be dealing with more than two genders -- in fact, significantly more.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon, indeed there were both genders for some patients.